# Determine the digit in a consecutive sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

All positive integers are written in order, one after another
$$1234567891011121314151617...$$

Which digits appears in the 206 787th position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the numbers with $4$ digits or less contribute 
$$10\cdot 1+90\cdot 2 +3\cdot 900+4\cdot 9000=38890.$$
digits.

Hence you need more $167897$ digits.

Therefore, your digit is in the 
$$\lfloor \frac{167897}{5} \rfloor+1$$
$5$ digit number.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the help! But i was wondering why you added a 1?? Can you please explain?

Comment: Also, from 1 to 9 we just have 9 numbers. So it should be 9⋅1+90⋅2+3⋅900+4⋅9000+5.90000+...

Answer (score 0):

I told my friend Ruby about it ([link](https://gist.github.com/7665ad65d237e0b50d3a)) and she thinks this is the solution:

```
concat(206787) = 3[5]7
```